# Postgresql - run second subquery conditional on results of first subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a table called `food`:

```
id  food_name    source_id  date
1 | 'apple'     | null     | '2019-01-01'
2 | 'apple_cake'| null     | '2019-01-02' 
3 | 'apple'     | null     | '2019-01-05'
4 | 'pear'      | null     | '2019-01-06'   
5 | 'apple'     | null     | '2019-01-07' 
6 | 'apple_cake'| 4        | '2019-01-10'
7 | 'grape'     | null     | '2019-01-15'
```

Some of the items have a `source_id`, which indicate what *other* product on the list it sourced its materials.

So I'm trying to make a query that, first, simply returns a row, like so:

**query1**

```
SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE date = '2019-01-01';
```

This will return the row with the `food_name` *apple*.

But then I want the query to run a second subquery that only executes *if* query1 above returns a row with `food_name` apple, and *only* apple. This query2 will look *specifically* for an apple_cake that has a `source_id` equal to the `id` from query1:

**query2**

```
SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE food_name = 'apple_cake'
    AND source_id = query1.id;
```

How can I combine these into a single query, where query2 is only run if query1 returns `food_name` apple, and the results from query1 and query2 are always returned?

**Note:** there are never duplicate `dates`

**Note 2:** when query1 and query2 are combined, it should only ever return either 0 rows, 1 row, or 2 rows max (it would only ever return 2 rows if it is returning an 'apple' and a connected 'apple_cake' rows).

Comment: If there are no duplicate dates why do you set LIMIT 1 in the 1st query?

Comment: D'oh. I'll remove that.

Comment: The 1st query returns max 1 row so the 2nd as you explained it will also return max 1 row, never 2 rows. If this is not what you want then you need to clarify.

Comment: So query1 will return at most 1 row, that's correct. The query2 should also return at most 1 row, for a combined 2 rows max. I'll clarify in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM food a
JOIN food b ON a.id = b.source_id
WHERE a.date = '2019-01-01' 
AND a.food_name = 'apple' 
AND b.food_name 'apple_cake
```